# UIScrollView setZoomScale sets the applied rotation back to Zero

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, rotation, calayer, zooming

I've been working on a maps replacement for quite a while now. The whole thing works with a `UIScrollView` backed by a `CATiledLayer`.

To rotate my map, i rotate the layer itself. (Using `CATransform3DMakeRotation`) Works pretty well so far =)

But if I ever call `setZoomScale` method the `CATransform3D` that is going to be submitted to my layer is resetting the rotation to 0.

My question is, is there any way to set the `zoomscale` of my scrollView without loosing the applied rotation?

The same problem exists for the pinch gestures.

//Additional Infos

To rotate around the current Position, i have to edit the anchor point. Maybe this is a problem for the scaling, too.

```
- (void)correctLayerPosition {
    CGPoint position    = rootView.layer.position;
    CGPoint anchorPoint = rootView.layer.anchorPoint;
    CGRect  bounds      = rootView.bounds;
    // 0.5, 0.5 is the default anchorPoint; calculate the difference
    // and multiply by the bounds of the view
    position.x              = (0.5 * bounds.size.width) + (anchorPoint.x - 0.5) *    bounds.size.width;
    position.y              = (0.5 * bounds.size.height) + (anchorPoint.y - 0.5) * bounds.size.height;
    rootView.layer.position = position;
}

- (void)onFinishedUpdateLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation {
    if (stayOnCurrentLocation) {
        [self scrollToCurrentPosition];
    }
    if (rotationEnabled) {
        CGPoint anchorPoint        = [currentConfig layerPointForLocation:newLocation];
        anchorPoint.x              = anchorPoint.x / rootView.bounds.size.width;
        anchorPoint.y              = anchorPoint.y / rootView.bounds.size.height;
        rootView.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
        [self correctLayerPosition];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement `scrollViewDidZoom:` delegate method and concatenate the two transforms to achieve desired effect:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
    CATransform3D scale = contentView.layer.transform;
    CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_4, 0, 0, 1);

    contentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, scale);
}
```

**EDIT**

I've got simpler idea! How about adding another view to the hierarchy with the rotation transform attached? Here's the proposed hierarchy:

- ScrollView

  - ContentView - the one returned by `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`

    - RotationView - the one with rotation transform

      - MapView - the one with all the tiles

I don't think that performance should be any concern here and it's worth trying.

Comment: Hey Bartosz, first of all, thank you for that post! But that didn't work for me... I have edited the anchor point to rotate around the current position. Maybe is that the problem? I will edit my post and add that code.

Comment: So it retained the rotation, but the rotation axis was wrong, right?

Comment: I can't really tell. Just from what i see, it rotates to much around a weird point. But the axis seems to be right.